# An alternative to WM_CREATE for a subclassed window

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

I have subclassed a child window with the old trick of:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&NewWndProc);
```

but the `WM_CREATE` message is never sent to it:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HBRUSH hBackground;

    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        // this is never received in my child window
        break;
    }
}
```

What is another message that would replace it somehow, where I can initiate some `HBRUSH`, `HBITMAP` variables that I intent to use in `WM_PAINT` or `WM_NOTIFY / NM_CUSTOMDRAW`?

Comment: You can't get WM_CREATE, it was already handled to give you the hWnd you use.  It is not obvious why you want a message, just initialize the variables before the SetWindowLongPtr() call.  If you absolutely want a message then just send it yourself with SendMessage().  But beware that the child window might already use WM_USER messages itself, RegisterWindowMessage() makes it safe.

Comment: On a side note, I strongly suggest to use the "new trick": [Safer subclassing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883/)

Comment: `WM_APP+xx` is normally suitable to provide extended message ids to a subclassed window.

Comment: The reason, why your subclassed window never receives a `WM_CREATE` message is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-create): *"Sent when an application requests that a window be created by calling the `CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow` function. (The message is sent before the function returns.)"* To work around this you could set up a [CBT hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx), and subclass the target window in your `HCBT_CREATEWND` callback.